# How to share on click handler between activities

Tags: java, android

Scenario, I have two activities, activity A, and activity B, they both extend from Activity, I also have a base menu xml on my ActionBar has onClick defined on a `handler()` method, how do I go about making this method available for my two activities without implementing it in both?, is making a common activity SuperClass the only way?

Comment: yes, implement it in the super class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic answer is that you could either make a common superclass, as you say, or you could create a helper class, where each Activity class that uses the method would have:

```
public void onSomethingClick(View target){
    MyActionBarHelperMethods.onSomethingClick(View target, /* whatever other things from this class you need */);
}
```

This can get kind of verbose if you have a lot of things you want to handle this way, but it's less verbose than implementing the same method everywhere.  It will also be painful to implement a new item in your action bar this way (since you'd have to add the method to every Activity you want to use it).  However, once again, it's less painful than having to modify the method in every place if you want to change it.

One way to possibly mitigate the headache when you want to add a new method would be to make each Activity implement an interface that contains all of the action bar methods you want them to have; most IDEs will realize you've added a new interface member and offer to add it to all of the implementing classes.